# Node.js - Async - multiple innercallbacks within a if statement

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, async.js

I'm using Node.js and the async library, however I keep seeing the error: `Callback was already called`.

I think I understand why I get the error, however I don't know if it is actually possible to do the following/how can resolve.

Basically I want both the innercallbacks to have completed before the outercallback is completed.

So the code with which I am facing this issue looks like:

```
async.forEachLimit(inData, 25, function (data, innercallback) {

    myJson.matches.forEach(function (oMatches) {
        if (data.$.id == oMatches.SourceId) {

            oMatches.ids.forEach(function (odId) {
                client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + data.$.id + "\")", {},
                    function (err) {
                        setTimeout(function () { innercallback(err) }, 2000);
                    });


                client.execute("g.V('" + data.$.id + "').addE('matches').to(g.V('xyz'))", {},
                    function (err) {
                        setTimeout(function () { innercallback(err) }, 2000);
                    });
            })

        } //there is no else case.

    });

}, outercallback);
```

Btw - I'm using `setTimeout` along with `async.forEachLimit` to reduce number of requests made to Azure (as I don't have too many)

Comment: Have a try for [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)?

Comment: I've updated the code. Please let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) can be used to ensure the order of asynchronized callbacks.

Take a look at [`async#AsyncFunction` in the official document](https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html)
 of `async` package

> Wherever we accept a Node-style async function, we also directly
>   accept an ES2017 async function. In this case, the async function will
>   not be passed a final callback argument, and any thrown error will be
>   used as the err argument of the implicit callback, and the return
>   value will be used as the result value. (i.e. a rejected of the
>   returned Promise becomes the err callback argument, and a resolved
>   value becomes the result.)

The third argument of the [`async#forEachLimit`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit) is an `async#AsyncFunction` so you can just return a promise from it and later resolve the promise to indicate that its job has finished.

Your code can be improved as follows,

```
async.forEachLimit(inData, 25, function (data, innercallback) {

  // we will wait for all async function in here to complete
  // then call the innercallback
  var asyncPromises = []

  myJson.matches.forEach(function (oMatches) {

    if (data.$.id == oMatches.SourceId) {

      oMatches.ids.forEach(function (odId) {
        asyncPromises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + data.$.id + "\")", {},
            function (err) {
              setTimeout(function () {
                if (err) {
                  reject(err)
                  return
                }
                resolve();
              }, 2000);
            });
        }))

        asyncPromises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          client.execute("g.V('" + data.$.id + "').addE('matches').to(g.V('xyz'))", {},
            function (err) {
              setTimeout(function () {
                if (err) {
                  reject(err)
                  return
                }
                resolve();
              }, 2000);
            });
        }))

      })

    } //there is no else case.

  })

  // Here we can ensure that innercallback is called only for once
  Promise.all(asyncPromises)
    .then(function () {
      innercallback(null)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      // handle the error here
      innercallback(err)
    })

}, outercallback);
```

Note that you should make sure you have `Promise` support in your Node environment. Builtin `Promise` is supported after Node v6. Check out [here](https://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-Promise).

**Updated**

I've misunderstood you internal callbacks which both of them must have completed before outercallback is called. I've corrected it with `Promise.all`, which takes an array of `Promise` as arguments and return a `Promise` which will be resolved if all sub-`Promise`s are all resolved or rejected if one of sub-`Promise`s is rejected. See [`Promise#all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

**Updated (2018.05.14)**

You have to ensure that every `innercallback` received from AsyncFunction (i.e. the 3rd argument of `async#forEachLimit`) of the `async` package is called only **once** during each iteration. Especially to be careful when you do `Array#forEach` in each iteration since it may make you call `innercallback` multiple times in an iteration.

I've update the code block above, where I take away all calls to `innercallback` from the callback of `client.execute` and put all `client.execute` into a promise. After that I collect all promises into the `asyncPromises` array.
`Promise#all` is used to ensure that all promises are resolved (i.e. all `client.execute`s are finished) then finally call `innercallback`. Or if one of the promise above is rejected and is caught in `Promise#catch`, call `innercallback` with the first argument to be the error reason.

Comment: Oh, I see. The `innercallback` in each iteration can only be called once. I'll update the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `innercallback` twice in case both `client.execute` throw error. You can use [async.parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) function or `Promise.all`, here is example of `async.parallel` and also you need to call `innercallback` function in `else` block

```
async.forEachLimit(inData, 25, function(data, innercallback) {
    async.eachSeries(myJson.matches, function(oMatches, callback) {
        if (data.$.id == oMatches.SourceId) {
            async.eachSeries(oMatches.ids, function(odId, callback) {
                async.parallel([
                    function(callback) {
                        client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + data.$.id + "\")", {}, callback);
                    },
                    function(callback) {
                        client.execute("g.V('" + data.$.id + "').addE('matches').to(g.V('xyz'))", {}, callback);
                    }
                ], callback);
            }, callback)

        } else {
            callback();
        }
    }, innercallback);
}, outercallback);
```

**Update:**  updated code, now using `async.eachSeries` in the place for `Array.forEach`

Comment: That didnt work - still get the `Callback was already called` error

Comment: Error - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @userMod2 `callback()` -> `process.nextTick(function() { callback() })`

Comment: @SergeyLapin thanks so that gets rid of the max call stack size error - however its actually running the `g.addV('test')` line second gremlin query

Comment: @SergeyLapin - cannot I do not something like `innercallback` and `innercallback2` ?

Comment: @SergeyLapin - I've simplified the issue in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284161/node-async-callback-was-already-called-using-2-for-loops-and-an-if-statement