# Node Async - Callback was already called - using 2 for loops and an if statement

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, async.js

Could someone please explain why I keep seeing the `Error: Callback was already called`.

I feel I have covered all cases - so why would be 'already called':

```
function addVertices(outercallback) {

    async.forEachLimit(fullData, 25, function (data, innercallback) {

        myJson.matches.forEach(function (oMatches) {
            if (data.$.id == oMatches.SourceId) {

                oMatches.Ids.forEach(function (oId) {

                    client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + oId + "\")", {}, (err, results) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return innercallback(console.error(err));
                        }

                        innercallback(null)
                    });

                })

            } 

        })

    }, outercallback);

}
```

Infact I also tried replacing that second forEach with `async.ForEach` as in the following, however is this the correct way to go?:

```
function addVertices(outercallback) {

    async.forEachLimit(fullData, 25, function (data, innercallback) {

        async.forEach(myJson, function (oMatches, innercallback2) {
            if (data.$.id == oMatches.SourceId) {

                oMatches.Ids.forEach(function (oId) {

                    client.execute("g.addV('test').property('id', \"" + oId + "\")", {}, (err, results) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return innercallback2(console.error(err));
                        }

                        innercallback2(null)
                    });

                })

            } 
            innercallback(null)

        })

    }, outercallback);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not the problem of `if`.

But because in each iteration of `async.forEachLimit`, the `innercallback` is called in the `myJson.matches.forEach(...)` which may have been called multiple times since `myJson.matches` may be more than 1 item.

Same problem in your 2nd code block.
In the inner `async.forEach`, the `innercallback2` is called in the `oMatches.Ids.forEach` which also may be called multiple times.

Therefore, `Error: Callback was already called` is argued when your second call (or any later calls) to `innercallback` occurs.

I've updated the solution with `Promise#all` to ensure the call of `innercallback` in [your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50266444/8579025).
See the **`Updated (2018.05.14)`** part and the code block.